# How to design a fitness function for binary logic network?

Tags: machine-learning, binary-data, genetic-algorithms, logic

Assume we have a directed graph of connected nodes, where each node represents a logical operator. Input for this logic operator are values on all edges leading to the node and the result is outputted to all edges leading from the node. A node can either be connected to another logic node or to an I/O node. Connections between nodes are subject to optimization by a Genetic algorithm.

Suppose the network is trained to simulate a XOR gate (or any other logic gate), however since there are only 4 possible inputs and 2 possible outputs, the fitness mountain is very sharp.

In other words the result can be right in either 4/4, 3/4, 2/4, 1/4 or 0/4 of all cases, and since there is nothing between these values of fitness, the networks have to make "jumps" across the fitness landscape in order to reach desired state.

Is there a way to design a fitness function of binary logic network to eliminate these "jumps" and to allow more gradual evolution of the network?

Comment: Could you, please, explain this: "In other words the result can be right in either 4/4, 3/4, 2/4, 1/4 or 0/4 of all cases". What does the first number represent? What is the meaning of the second?

Comment: It's fraction. Four quarters, three quarters etc.

Comment: Oh, now I see. It was pretty obvious, but for some reason it did not occur to me that it were fractions. :/ Although the fitness surface could be steep, this way of defining the fitness function is natural and I would go for it. It follows formulation of your problem. A minimal "jump" is `1/2^n` and I don't think there is a way to avoid jumps. Maybe you can assign different weights to different valuations of propositional variables, but that would bias your network to certain truth assignments. If you're ok with that, maybe that could reshape the fitness function surface.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about the need for large leaps in fitness in your genetic algorithm, simply using one method or another to increase the short or medium term survivability of individuals so they have more generations to essentially jump the fitness gap before becoming instinct may do the trick. There are several not-so-clever ways to do this, and many more clever ways. A simple example might be to decrease the % of individuals killed off per generation directly by modifying your selection process.